# SSIS - Iterating with SQL Server Data in ForEachLoop to Dataflow with Oracle Backend and Inserting Results to SQL Server

Tags: oracle, ssis

Hey EXPERIENCED SSIS DEVELOPERS, I need your help.

High-Level Requirements

1. Query SQL Server table (on a different server than my SSIS server) resulting in about 200-300k records results set.
2. Use three output colums for each row to lookup date in Oracle database.
3. Insert or Update SQL Server table with results.
4. Use SSIS.
5. SQL Server 2008

Sounds easy, right?

Here is what I have done:

1. Created on Control Flow Execute SQL Task that gets a recordset from SQL Server. Very fast, easy query, like select field1, field2, field 3 from table where condition > 0. That's it. Takes less than a second.
2. Created a variable (evaluated as expression) for the Oracle query that uses the results set from the above in the WHERE clause.
3. Created a ForEachLoop Container that takes the results (from #1 above) for each row in the recordset and runs it through a Data Flow that uses the Oracle query (from #2 above) with Data access mode: SQL command from variable against an Oracle data source. Fast, simple query with only about 6 columns returned.
4. Data Conversion - obvious reasons - changing 3 columns from Oracle data types to SQL Server data types.
5. OLE DB Destination to insert to SQL Server using Fast Load to staging table.

It works perfectly! Hooray! Bad news - it is very, very slow. When I say slow, I mean it process 3000 records per hour. Holy moly - so freaking slow.

Question: am I missing a way to speed it up? It seems like the ForEachLoop Container is the bottleneck. Growl.

Important Points: 
- I have NO write access in Oracle environment, so don't even suggest a potential solution that requires it. Not a possibility. At all.

- Oracle sources do not allow for direct parameter definition. So no SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE WHERE ?. Don't suggest it - doesn't work.

Ideas 
- Should I find a way to break down the results of the Execute SQL task and send them through several ForEachLoop Containers for faster processing?

- Is there another design that is more appropriate?
- Is there a script I can use that is faster?
- Would it be faster to create a temporary table in memory and populate it - then use the results to bulk insert to SQL Server? Does this work when using an Oracle data source?
- ANY OTHER IDEAS?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand 1, 2 & 3. A query runs against a SQL Server table and based on the results of that *something* resulting in a unique query being generated for Oracle source.

Comment: Also, where is the time being spent in the package? Turn on Logging, use a SQL Server OLE DB Connection and log OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute events. Then you should be able to tell where the time is being spent

Comment: Here is a better way to ask the question. If you had my requirements, how would you solve the problem in SSIS? Use data from a SQL Server database table to bump against large data source in Oracle database and record/log matches/ results? The time is being spent iterating through the Oracle data and inserting into a staging table.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements so I cannot say what the best approach is. I'm sure it's clear in your mind what your needs are but not being familiar with your environment and end goal, it's hard to provide input.

Comment: Two approaches: 1. Use a lookup component (definitely not a for each). 2. Copy the Oracle table locally and perform an UPDATE (this will be likely be quickest if you have the space to store the table). Try those approaches and post back any questions. This will make your requirements clearer to us.

Comment: I am supposed to bump a SQL Server table against an Oracle database and return the matches. The ForEach is killing me in the original solution since it makes the call to the Oracle database around 300k times.

Comment: Thanks ElectricLlama. Based on your response, I think you are understand what I am trying to do. I tried the Lookup last night (without the ForEach) - there are multiple matches in the Oracle database and Lookup only matches on one record. Darn. The Oracle databaes is VERY, VERY large, so bringing over the entire recordset (around 400 trillion records) isn't going to work. I am working on trying to logically tighten my import based on the data in the SQL Server table. I'm looking up Merge Join to see if that may work.

Comment: So Merge Join is a bust. I never used it before now and didn't realize both data sets were fully executed in memory before merging. D'oh.